# XML Schema + complexType element + Alternative to sequence

Tags: xsd, complextype

I want to create an XML Schema - an XSD file - to apply on XML documents.
Let's consider the following XML document :

```
<root>
    <a />
    <b />
    <c />
    <a />
    <a />
    <b />
</root>
```

Where the following desired constraints are respected :

1. < root > is the root element.
2. The < a >, < b > and < c > elements can appears an unbounded number of times.
3. The < a >, < b > and < c > elements are not grouped. For instance, an  element can preceded and followed a < b > element.

If I had to create an XML schema to apply on the example XML document I would start as the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema  targetNamespace="http://doesnotmatter.com/"
            xmlns="http://doesnotmatter.com/"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="root"
                min="1"
                max="1">
        <complexType>

            <!-- ? -->

        </complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

I do not know how to fill the < complexType > element in my schema.
I can not use a < sequence > element because of the 3rd constraint.
How could I achieve my schema to respect all the 3 constraints.

**Edit**

The choice element was the keystone to my problem.
Here is the XML schema corresponding to my needs described above :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema  targetNamespace="http://doesnotmatter.com/"
            xmlns="http://doesnotmatter.com/"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>

      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="a" />
        <xs:element name="b" />
        <xs:element name="c" />
      </xs:choice>

    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your model for root is: repeatedly choose from amongst these possibilities: a, b, c.  Is that it?  The operative word is choose as in choice.  Maybe I am missing something, but the answer seems pretty obvious.